# Python how to check if something is alphanumeric except for certain values

Tags: python, python-3.x, alphanumeric

I'm trying to determine whether a string is an email or not. The requirements are of course the @email.com, the first letter has to be capital and it has to be alphanumeric, except for the @ and the period. What I was looking for is whether there is a way for me to check whether the email is alphanumeric, except for the period and the @

What I would like is for the code to return True for the email if and only if the first letter is capital, it has the @emuail.com and it is alphanumeric except for the @ and the period. What I would like is a solution that checks for alphanumerics except for the @ and the period in the @emauil.com portion of the email.

I was thinking I could separate the email at the @email part and check for .isalnum for everything before the @email, but I just wanted to see if there was an easier way.

Here is my current code, which of course returns all False, because of the @ and the period:

```
emails = ['Hello@emuail.com', 'Hello2@emuail.comaas', 'hello--1@emuail.com']

result = []

for idx, email in enumerate(emails):
  if '@emuail.com' in email and email[0].isupper() and email.isalnum():
    result.append(True)
  else:
    result.append(False)

print(result)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if a string is an email address?

Comment: Yes,  I would. But it has to be only alphanumeric except for the @ and the .

Comment: Well, the way your question is worded, you would accept strings like `a@.`, `a@b.`, `@b.c`, `a.b@` and so on, which can't be email addresses. So it's important to be specific about what you're asking; please see [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the only thing I needed help figuring out was the alphanumeric part. I will edit my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing string searching/testing that gets even modestly complicated, it's usually better (more readable and more flexible) to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re).

```py
import re

# from https://emailregex.com/
email_pattern = re.compile(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)")

emails = ['Hello@emuail.com', 'Hello2@emuail.comaas', 'hello--1@emuail.com']

for email in emails:
    if email_pattern.match(email):
        print(email)
```

Note that hyphens are allowed in email addresses, but if you want to disallow them for some reason, delete them from the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This generator will return valid emails.  If you want more rules, add them to the condition.  `re` is better, however.

```
emails = ['Hello@emuail.com', 'Hello2@emuail.comaas', 'hello--1@emuail.com']

[i for i in emails if '@' in i and i[-4:] == '.com' and i.split('@')[0].isalnum() and '@' is not i[-5]]
```